# How to make wait for a pthread of a GTK window to close

Tags: c, pthreads, gtk

I have a code that takes a URL and downloads it using libcurl and displays a nice loading bar in another window, in another part of my code, I run the downloadFile function in a for loop, and what happens is that it first downloads the files and then displays all the progress windows, what am I doing wrong?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <byteswap.h>
#ifndef _WIN32
    #include <sys/stat.h>
#endif

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#include <pthread.h>

struct MemoryStruct {
  uint8_t* memory;
  size_t size;
};

struct PathFileStruct {
    char* file_path;
    FILE* file_pointer;
};

GtkWidget *progress_bar;
GtkWidget *button;
GtkWidget *window;

//Thread
pthread_t thread;
int thread_running = 0;

CURL* new_handle;

//LibCurl progress function
int progress_func(void *ptr, double t, double d, double ultotal, double ulnow)
{
    if(t == 0) {
        gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(progress_bar), 0);
        return 0;
    }

    gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(progress_bar), d/t);
    while(gtk_events_pending())
        gtk_main_iteration();

    return 0;
}

static size_t write_data(void* data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* file_stream)
{
    size_t written = fwrite(data, size, nmemb, file_stream);
    return written;
}

//LibCurl download function
void *download(void *ptr)
{
    if (new_handle) {
        curl_easy_perform(new_handle);
        curl_easy_cleanup(new_handle);
    }
    thread_running = 0;
    return NULL;
}


//Start download function
void start_download(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    if(thread_running)
        return;

    thread_running = 1;
    if(pthread_create(&thread, NULL, download, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        thread_running = 0;
        return;
    }
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
}

void *progressDialog() {
    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);

    //Create window
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "LibCurl Download Progress Bar");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 50);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    //Create progress bar
    progress_bar = gtk_progress_bar_new();
    gtk_progress_bar_set_show_text(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(progress_bar), TRUE);
    gtk_progress_bar_set_text(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(progress_bar), "Downloading");

    //Create container for the window
    GtkWidget *main_box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), main_box);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(main_box), progress_bar, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    start_download(window, NULL);

    //gtk_main();
}

int downloadFile(char *download_url, char *output_path) {
    new_handle = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(new_handle, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(new_handle, CURLOPT_URL, download_url);
    curl_easy_setopt(new_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(new_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(new_handle, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progress_func);
    curl_easy_setopt(new_handle, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, progress_bar);

    FILE* output_file = fopen(output_path, "wb");
    if (!output_file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: The file \"%s\" couldn't be opened. Will exit now.\n", output_path);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Downloading file \"%s\".\n", download_url);

    struct PathFileStruct* struct_to_save = malloc(sizeof(struct PathFileStruct));
    struct_to_save->file_path = malloc(strlen(output_path) + 1);
    strcpy(struct_to_save->file_path, output_path);
    struct_to_save->file_pointer = output_file;
    curl_easy_setopt(new_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, output_file);
    curl_easy_setopt(new_handle, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, struct_to_save);
    pthread_t inputTimer;
    pthread_create(&inputTimer, NULL, &progressDialog, NULL);
    pthread_join(inputTimer, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your app is still of the single thread flow with the immediate join after the thread create.

Comment: @273K What do you mean?